# Android: Google Drive Api. Is there a UI for Google Drive

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-api

I am wondering do we have to write our own UI to display Google Drive Files/Folder or do they already have UI built within the API.

I am also looking at the Storage Access Framework but it only show the google drive if you have installed the Google Drive application in you device

Answer (score 0):

**By adding this dependencies you can access google drive in your project.**

`dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.20.0'
}`

And this link will help you to better understand how to use and what are the features provided by this API.
https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Google Drive API has readily available [UI components with the help of ActivityBuilders](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro#activity_builders), namely, CreateFileActivityBuilder and OpenFileActivityBuilder.

CreateFileActivityBuilder helps you quickly create a file, set its initial folder, title, contents, and metadata. The class also implements a simple UI that allows a user to specify the file's title and destination folder.

OpenFileActivityBuilder helps you easily open a file selected by the user. The class displays a simple UI to let the user navigate and select from a list of files that match the specified MIME types.

You can see this builders in use in this [Drive Quickstart sample](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart).